# Dynamically updating only the Manipulate local variable

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Say I have an array of data arrays, assigned to a temporary variable `dat`, and I'd like to switch between plots of the arrays using Manipulate. For example:

```
RandomData := Table[RandomReal[], {ii, 1, 3}, {jj, 1, 10}];
dat = RandomData
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  dat[[ii]]
  ]
 , {ii, 1, Length@dat, 1}]
```

Later, I generate another set of data arrays, and I want the same kind of dynamic plot. But I'd like to assign the data to the same temporary variable and reuse the plotting code to avoid needing to rename all the data variables within the Manipulate block (in general, the block could be long and complicated with many calls to `dat`).

```
dat = RandomData
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  dat[[ii]]
  ]
 , {ii, 1, Length@dat, 1}]
```

The problem, of course, is that if I reassign a new value to `dat`, then the earlier Manipulate plot updates with the new value. But I would like both Manipulate outputs to show the value of `dat` as it was when the Manipulate block was called!

Is there a way to restrict the dynamic updating only to the local variable `ii` (i.e. to disable updating the variable `dat`)? Or is there perhaps an entirely different way to go about this, with Module, perhaps?

Comment: This is what [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scope the updating of `dat`. e.g.

```
DynamicModule[{dat = RandomData}, 
 Manipulate[ListPlot[dat[[ii]]], {ii, 1, Length@dat, 1}]]
```

Comment: Ahh, I knew Mathematica somehow had my back! Thank you.